# Añadir paneles a una ventana con Pyqt

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, interfaz-gráfica, qmainwindow

Estoy creando una interfaz gráfica con Pyqt5 pero al crear la ventana principal QMainWindow quería que al pulsar sobre un botón del menú me abra un panel de pestañas en la misma ventana.

```
parent.addWidget(tabWidget)
```

Estaba tratando de añadirlo como un widget pero no me deja, y no veo ningún otro método que me pueda servir.

*AttributeError: 'MainWindow' object has no attribute 'addWidget'*

El código es para la ventana principal:

```
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.initUI()


def initUI(self):         

    menubar = self.menuBar()
    #Menu de busqueda
    fileMenu = menubar.addMenu('Buscar...')

    impMenu = QAction('Productos', self)
    #impAct = QAction('Import mail', self) 
    #impMenu.addAction(impAct)
    #newAct = QAction('New', self)        
    #fileMenu.addAction(newAct)
    fileMenu.addAction(impMenu)
    fileMenu.triggered.connect(self.buscarProductos())

    self.setGeometry(50, 50, 1100, 800)
    self.setWindowTitle('IA - Análisis datos')    
    self.show()

def buscarProductos(self):
    #limpiarPantalla()
    fileName = "."
    tabdialog = BuscarProductosScreen(fileName, self)
    tabdialog.show()
```

Y la ventana a la que trato llamar:

```
class BuscarProductosScreen():

def __init__(self, filename, parent):
    #super(BuscarProductosScreen, self).__init__(parent)

    fileInfo = QFileInfo(filename)

    tabWidget = QTabWidget()
    tabWidget.addTab(GeneralTab(fileInfo), "General")

    parent.addWidget(tabWidget)

    self.setWindowTitle("Tab Dialog")
```

Comment: Si deseas ayuda debes proveer un [mcve], ademas lee [ask] para que mejores tu pregunta :)

Comment: En mi opinión, para que se entienda os debería de añadir un cacho enorme de código y con lo cual hace engorroso leer la pregunta, pero si lo quieres ahí va

Comment: En mi opinión deberias leer que es un [mcve], ¿lo has hecho? :)

Comment: No se entiende así tampoco?

Comment: Esta mejor, pero como te dije lee el enlace, por otro lado tú dices: *me abra un panel de pestañas en la misma ventana.*, ¿qué significa eso?

Comment: Por aquí se le llama al QTabWidget, un panel con diferentes pestañas

Comment: ¿tú quieres que cada vez que se presione el item *productos* se añada un widget de `GeneralTab` en el QTabWidget que debe ser el centralWidget?, por tu codigo parece que no tienes los conceptos claros de tu implementación, podrias quizas con una imagen ilustrar lo que deseas obtener.

Comment: Lo que quiero es abrir en la QMainWindow un QTabWidget

Comment: ¿quieres obtener lo siguiente; https://imgur.com/a/5Yy5SyV?

Comment: Si, exacto, eso es lo que quiero hacer   :)

Comment: ¿te funciono mi solución?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tú tienes los siguientes errores:

- En la coneccion con la señal `triggered` debes pasarle el nombre de la función, no la función evaluada, lo correcto es: `fileMenu.triggered.connect(self.buscarProductos)`.
- los widgets no tiene el método addWidget() por ello te lanza el error.

Por otro lado antes de escribir es mejor tener un esquema de lo que se espera tener, por lo que la estructura debe ser la siguiente:

```
MainWindow
└── centralwidget
    └── tabwidget
        ├── GeneralTab
        ├── GeneralTab
        ├── ...
        └── GeneralTab
```

Entonces como vemos solo debe haber un QTabWidget y en el codigo de BuscarProductosScreen tu estas creando otros(por otro lado BuscarProductosScreen no es un widget asi que `tabdialog.show()` no funcionara), ademas veo innecesario crear esa clase por lo que la eliminare para evitar confusiones.

Usando lo anterior obtenemos lo siguiente:

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):     
        centralwidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(centralwidget)
        lay = QVBoxLayout(centralwidget)

        menubar = self.menuBar()
        fileMenu = menubar.addMenu('Buscar...')
        impMenu = QAction('Productos', self)
        fileMenu.addAction(impMenu)
        fileMenu.triggered.connect(self.buscarProductos)

        self.tabWidget = QTabWidget()
        lay.addWidget(self.tabWidget)

        self.setWindowTitle('IA - Análisis datos')    
        self.show()

    def buscarProductos(self):
        #limpiarPantalla()
        filename = "."
        fileInfo = QFileInfo(filename)
        self.tabWidget.addTab(GeneralTab(fileInfo), "General")
```